# Reading each non-English character from a file

Tags: c#, string, encoding, character, non-english

Let's say a file has non-English text. We can read the file contents with FileIO.ReadLinesAsync method. Now each line contains set of characters. How to extract each letter (non-English alphabet) from this string?  Here i represented my question in C# code.

```
   List<string> finalAlphabets = new List<string>();
        IList<string> alphabetLines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(_languageFile,UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        if (alphabetLines.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (string alphabetLine in alphabetLines)
            {
                //lets say alphabetLine has "కాకికు", here i want to extract each letter from this and i want to add to finalAlphabets list 
                finalAlphabets.Add("కా"); // How to extract this letter from alphabetLine variable. If you look at the Length of alphabetLine , it shows 6, but actually in Telugu language it is 3 letter word.             
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please ask one concrete question per post. In current state it looks like you need good tutorial on strings/encoding/file IO and general programming as an answer which makes it too broad for SO. Possibly answer to your question is contained in [TextInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, but it is hard to see if you are actually looking for that type of info.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. I just simplified my question. Please let me know how to user TextInfo class to solve my problem.

Comment: It is indeed better now. You just need to figure out what "letter" means for you and you are all set. In many cases just iterating characters would be enough, but it is hard to say - many hieroglyphs span 2 characters and symbols with accents may span several characters of the string too (especially if de-normalized, but that is rarely a case and you can easily normalize string first).

Comment: Yes. For English it is just one character per alphabet. But, it is not the case for non-English. That's why i want to store in list of Strings. But, how to extract each alphabet from the "alphabetLine" string variable? How Normalizing the string help to extract each alphabet?

Comment: Can you provide an example of string which demonstrates case where you want multiple characters per "letter"? (Because you don't have one in the post...)

Comment: I gave the example string with 4 Telugu language alphabets "అఆఇఈ". We can't store each alphabet in a c# char variable. So, i want to store in List<String> variable finalAlphabets in my example. So, I want to extract the alphabet (lets say అ) from the above string and then want to add to  finalAlphabets. Like finalAlphabets.Add("అ"); How can i extract that each alphabet. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you have problem with than. The string in your sample is 4 characters long and if you can't separate it into 4 characters I don't know what can help you.

Comment: Sorry Alexei for wrong sample. I just updated my post with other 3 letters from Telugu language. Now, i want to extract each letter from that given word. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is set of text information classes - `TextInfo`, `StringInfo`, and in particular you are likely looking for [`TextElementEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which lets one to find "text element" boundaries.

Simplified sample from MSDN article:

```
var myTEE = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator( "కాకికు");
while (myTEE.MoveNext())  {
     Console.WriteLine( "[{0}]:\t{1}\t{2}", 
         myTEE.ElementIndex, myTEE.Current, myTEE.GetTextElement() );
}
```

Produces following output:

```
[0]:  కా  కా
[2]:  కి  కి
[4]:  కు  కు
```

Comment: Awesome Alexei. Thanks for your patience and providing exact solution what i want. I am writing a UWP app. You helped me a lot!

Comment: above code is working for most of the alphabets. But, while writing languages like Telugu or Hindi, we used to have mixture of two or alphabets to get new letter. Two examples in Telugu are "క్ష" , "ల్య" etc. Above code not extracting such letters properly. in other words,  
 
    var myTEE = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator( "క్షల్య");  

giving 4 elements, but i want to extract them as two elements "క్ష" and "ల్య". Do i need to specify any langue codes to extract in that way? please help. Thanks again.

Comment: That is way outside of my knowledge. Ask  new question with a lot of details.